# Get list or count of registered users for application

Tags: instagram

Using Instagram's API, is there any way to request a list or count of an application's registered users?

Instagram's [real-time subscriptions](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/#user-subscriptions) can send notifications whenever a registered user posts to their feed, but I haven't found a way to get a list of those users, or even a count. This is easy enough to store server-side, but seems like something which should be discoverable.

Comment: I tried to address your question. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding your question or need to clarify something further.

Comment: I appreciate the thoroughness of your answer, but it doesn't really add anything beyond restating the question and a cursory google search. Maybe I should rephrase it to be more subscription-specific.

Comment: I would rephrase as it's not clear what you're ultimately after. I tried to address your question from a few view points.

Answer (score 1):

### Your Question

> Using Instagram's API, is there any way to request a list of an application's registered users?

A quick search yielded no results for such a functionality. This make sense, though, since Instagram wouldn't want to open up all its users to any app designer.

**Your App**

If you want the number of users using your app, then you can easily track this yourself.

**Instagram App**

As mentioned before, Instagram probably won't provide even basic count information about its registered users. Presumably, this is valuable information.

### Your Example

> Instagram's real-time subscriptions can send notifications whenever a registered user posts to their feed...

This is true, but with very limited scope. [The subscriptions below](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/#subscriptions) are based on users who are using your app or other simple criteria such as tags or geographic data.

> - **Users**: receive notifications when users who have registered with your    application post new photos.
> - **Tags**: receive notifications when a new    photo is tagged with tags of your choosing
> - **Locations**: receive    notifications when new photos are posted and tagged with a specific    location
> - **Geographies**: receive notifications when a new photos are    posted in an arbitrary geographical location as defined by a center    point
>   and radius

Comment: A user subscription will trigger whenever any registered app's users update. But there doesn't appear to be way to know how many users will be triggering those updates. With a moderate user base, those triggers could add up pretty quickly.

Comment: I'm looking into this further. However, couldn't you track this yourself? I suspect their API might be lacking in this type of information.

Comment: The docs also state the following on handling data: ["The changed data is not included in the payload, so it is up to you how you'd like to fetch the new data. For example, you may decide only to fetch new data for specific users, or after a certain number of photos have been posted."](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/#receiving-updates) This basically addresses the concern in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have found this far there is no IG API, however as already indicated you can keep track on your app.  HOWEVER, what has not been pointed out is that you won't be made aware if users terminate their account or revoke your app so the count's might be a little off. (or worse if you didnt start keeping track since the public launch of your app)

You could test on a periodic basis if you still have access, but that would require additional code, and a lot of API calls if you app has a lot of users.  I hope that IG will add this function at some point.